# Besides Browsers, what other Technologies are Impacted by the Deprecation of SHA-1?

Tags: hash, public-key-infrastructure, sha

I am aware that from January 2017, browsers will start rejecting, or at least warning, users browsing sites offering SHA-1-signed certificates.

Would a service be impacted if the system does not have any interaction with browsers?

In other words, what other technologies besides browsers will be impacting services over the use of SHA-1-signed certificates?

Comment: This specific deadline for SHA-1 is only for browsers, i.e. in other environments other deadlines might apply. But deprecating weak algorithms like SSL 3.0, RC4, MD4, RSA-1024 etc is done all the time so there is nothing really special about this SHA-1 deprecation.

Answer (score 1):

> Would a service be impacted if the system does not have any
>   interaction with browsers?

Not by the browser sha-1 deprecation. However, sha-1 is used and being deprecated on many other scenarios. Digital signatures, TLS communications in general (clients may start refusing it soon or already refusing it), authentication systems. It should be abandoned as soon as possible, because unlike browsers, in other scenarios the deprecation might not be so well coordinated and planned and just hit you one day.